# Compare forloop.index|modulo:4 with 0 in Liquid (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to get my home.html layout to return a row for every forth column. But this keeps up giving me true everytime.

{%- if forloop.index0|modulo:4 == 0 -%}{%- endif -%}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that Jekyll expects an *end_of_string* but found *pipe* in `forloop.index0|modulo:4 == 0`.

You have to assign the *modulo* calculation to a variable and then use it in the *if* clause, inside the *for* loop:

```
{% assign loopindex = forloop.index0 | modulo: 4 %}
{%- if loopindex == 0 -%}
<p style="background-color:red">Hey look! I'm a fourth element</p>
{%- endif -%}
```